# Expected Value of Minimum of Exponential and Uniform Variables

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, random-variables, expectation

> I have been stuck for hours now  trying to figure out the following question: Say that $X$ and $Y$ are independent variables. $X$ is uniformly distributed over $(0,2)$, while $Y$ is exponentially distributed with mean $1$. Let $W = \min\{X,Y\}$. What is the $E[W]$?

My solution so far goes like this:

$$F_W(w) =   P(W > t) = P(X>t,Y>t)  =  P(X>t)P(Y>t)$$
$$=\Biggl(\int_t^2 \frac{1}{2} \, dx\Biggl)\Biggl(\int_t^\infty e^{-y} \, dy\Biggl)$$
$$=e^{-t}-\frac{1}{2}te^{-t}$$

I then take the derivative of this to find the density function of W which ends up equaling:

$$-e^{-t}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}+\frac{1}{2}te^{-t}$$

In order to find the expected value, I then attempt to integrate like so:

$$\int  t \Biggl(-e^{-t}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}+\frac{1}{2}te^{-t}\Biggl)dt$$

The issue is that this seems to come out with a very complex answer that I don't think is correct. Is there a formula I'm not picking up on or a simpler way to compute these problems then the method I am using?

Comment: Your integral seems to have the wrong sign.  By the way, $\int t e^{-t}\,dt = -(t+1)e^{-t}+C$ and $\int t^2 e^{-t}\,dt = -(t^2+2t+2)e^{-t}+c$

Comment: Where you wrote $F_w(w)$ you need $F_W(w).$ Without that distinction, what would $\Pr(W\le w)$ mean? And various computations would become impossible.

Comment: Where you wrote $F_w(w)$ I corrected it, writing $F_W(w).$ You need $F_W(w) = \Pr(W\le w),$ <b>not</b> $F_W(w) = \Pr(W>w),$ and certainly not $F_W(w) = {}$some function of some variable called $t$ instead of $w.$ Other than that you're on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

First, $\Pr(W > w) = 1-F_W(w)$.

Second, $$\int_0^2(1-F_W(w))\,dw = \left[w(1-F_W(w))\right]_0^2+\int_0^2 wf_W(w) \, dw = 0 + E[W]=E[W].$$
So you do not need to take the derivative of $F_W(w)$ at all, nor you need to compute an integral that involves a quadratic expression.

Comment: You still need to find $\int_{0}^{2}\left(e^{-w}-\frac{1}{2}we^{-w}\right)\,dw$